# How to pass empty object in $project , mongoose (^5.2.13)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to pass empty object in $project in mongoose.aggregate. But I am getting error

```
{
    "ok": 0,
    "errmsg": "Invalid $project specification: specification must have at least one field",
    "code": 40177,
    "codeName": "Location40177",
    "name": "MongoError"
}
```

My query is

```
Catalog.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {}
    },
    {
        $project: {

        }
    }
])
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the `MongoDB` [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#restrictions),

> MongoDB 3.4 and later produces an error if the $project specification
>   is an empty document.

So you won't be able to use `$project` with an empty document and check the version of MongoDB in your system, now it is greater or equal to 3.4 which causes the error. Or if you want to use `$project` with an empty document follow this [mongoose document](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/compatibility.html).